# How to pass arguments in constrain and objective function in isres function in R?

Tags: r, nlopt

I wants to pass argument values for constrain and objective function in isres function in r. 
Since I might need to use nonlinear functional I am using isres function.
My codes are as below.

```
############## DATA PREPARETION ##########

per1 <- c(50,24,100,12,33,80,120,75,54,32)

per2 <- c(100,241,141,124,130,102,451,141,471,121)

############## CONSTRAIN FUNCTION DEFINATION ##########

constfunction <- function (per1,per2,x) {

  total <- 0 

  for (i in 1:length(per2)) {
    total <- per2[i]*x[i] + total
  }

  total <- total - 1000
  return (total)
}

############## OBJECTIVE FUNCTION DEFINATION ##########

objfunction <- function(per1, per2,x) {

  solution <- 0

  for (i in 1:length(per1)) {
    solution <- per1[i]*x[i] + solution
  }

  return(solution)

}

############## OPTIMIZATION ##########

n <- length(per1)

res0 <- isres ( x0=c(rep(0,n)),
                fn = objfunction,
                lower = c(rep(0,n)),
                upper = c(rep(1,n)),
                hin = NULL,
                heq = constfunction,
                maxeval = 100000,
                xtol_rel = 1e-06,
                nl.info = TRUE,
)
```

This gives error as below
argument "x" is missing, with no default.

Since x is variable, how can I provide x in code??
Also How to provide per1 and per2? i.e how to provide arguments to objective function and constrain function in isres in R?

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving x parameter inside isres to your functions objfunction and constfunction.

Let's say you have a function that needs 3 parameters a, b, c

```
f1 <- function(a, b, c){ 
   a + b + c 
}
```

If you are calling f1 within another function, the 3 parameters need to be supplied within the function.

In my example:

```
#
# Let's imagine from some calculation a get this 2 values
p.2 <- 9
p.3 <- 8
#
# I call lapply, and use f1 function:
lapply(1:3, f1, p.2, p.3)
```

If you check the declaration of lapply, you'll find:

```
lapply(X, FUN, ...)
#
x -> vector
FUN -> function to be applied to each element of X
... -> any other parameter that FUN may need
```

So f1 is getting parameter a from the values 1:3, parameter b from p.2 and c from p.3